# What is The Blackening referencing or satirizing with Clifton having an Android phone instead of an iPhone?

Tags: the-blackening

In the horror comedy film *[The Blackening](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11703244/reference/)* (2022), Shanika (played by X Mayo) ribs Clifton (played by Jermaine Fowler) for owning an Android phone instead of an iPhone.

Relevant dialogue:

> **Clifton:** But then my Hyundai died up the road.
> […]
> And I get here, they don't even have my charger.
> They have iPhone, I have Android.
>
> **Shanika:** Damn. I'm sorry, that does suck.
>
> **Clifton:** It does.
>
> **Shanika:** Not the car, the Android.
>
> **Clifton:** You're funny. We all know Androids have the superior operating systems.
>
> **Shanika:** Wrong! That's wrong. But it's okay. I'm gonna help yo ass get gas despite your opinions.

Dialogue in a separate scene from the above:

> **Clifton:** Anyway, do you guys have an Android charger?
>
> **Shanika:** I told you, we don't support that.

I understand that *The Blackening* satirizes the common tropes involving Black characters in horror films. Is this a nod to a particular trope, or is it a cultural thing in the US?

I don't get why Shanika mocks Clifton's phone choice. Android phones come in various brands and models, some as expensive as iPhones. And Clifton never says what kind of Android phone he has.

**What is *The Blackening* trying to say or satirize with this joke?**

Comment: I don't think it's a black thing. I think it's an *"Iphone/Android users think their OS is superior"* joke

Comment: @Valorum which seems to be a US thing as well. I saw a recent tweet considering a man owning an Android phone to be "a red flag" when dating.

Comment: People outside the US don’t look down on android phones? It could be a racial stereotype joke related to lower income. One main reason why many people choose android phones is they can be more affordable.

Comment: I'm surprised that in context he didn't get more of a ribbing for the Hyundai ;))

Answer (score 1):

In doing research for the other question dealing with this movies choice of weapon, crossbows - I found a bit of trivia on IMDB

> Apple does not allow use of their iPhone devices by any villains in media.  Clifton therefore uses an Android phone.

Not sure when this happens on the plot of the movie but I thought it was interesting bit of info.